# CFormatter lose decimals with simple-csv-export extension

Tags: php, csv, yii, yii-extensions

I make csv upload from this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/401/simple-csv-export
and found errors that made the format lose decimals in double values.

The class looks like this

```
<?php

class MyFormatter extends CFormatter
{
...
   public function formatMoney($value)
   {
        FilesFuncs::DebToFile('formatMoney  $value::' . print_r($value, true), false); // debugging to file : i see result double values WITHOUT decimals
        return round(floatval($value),2);
   }
...
```

In control I run :

```
$dst_filename= 'registers-upto--' . strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") . ".csv";
CsvExport::export( $GoodsList,
array(  'good_id'=>array('number' ,'fixed8' ),
'name'=>array(),
'price'=>array('number' ,'money'  ), // MONEY TYPE
'discount'=>array('number' ,'fixed8' ),
```

In CsvExport.php file :

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $r = '';
  foreach ($coldefs as $col => $config) {

    if (isset($row[$col])) {
      $val = $row[$col];
       FilesFuncs::DebToFile('$col::' . print_r($col, true), false);
       FilesFuncs::DebToFile('$val::' . print_r($val, true), false); // HERE $val is WITH decimals
       foreach ($config as $conf)
         if (!empty($conf)) {
           $val = Yii::app()->format->format( $val, $conf ); // debugging to file : i see result double values returns  WITHOUT decimals
...
```

In database field described as price double(12,2). What is matter and how to fix it ?

I am using Yii 1.1.14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your number format uses commas (`','`) to separate between numbers and decimal places? In that case, you will need to enclose your numbers in double quotes (`"`) so that the CSV file doesn't think the comma in your numbers are separators.

Also, set `$separator` options in class `CsvExport` (or create a subclass) with something other than a `","` to avoid errors.